# 304 Not Modified

Tags: ajax, drupal, caching

I've written a Drupal block and an ajax call to refresh it(block content) whenever the block is loaded.(It's because i have enabled the cache).

But now my problem is whenever i go to a cached page, i'm getting a response - "304 Not Modified". Because of that i'm not getting the correct content i want.

I found a solution such that to pass a number - **new Date().getTime()** - so that although the page is cached, since the next request is having another number, i'm getting correct values. But this seems quite "ugly". :)

Is there another way to do this task?

thanks....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [cacheexclude](http://drupal.org/project/cacheexclude) module to exclude that URL from cache.